# What is the difference between had to and had to be?

Tags: passive-voice, active-vs-passive

I might ask in this way: Why passive is used in this sentence? Which one make more sense? Is first sentence passive?

> Many had to be wrestled into straitjackets.

Or

> Many had to wrestle into straitjackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is just the passive/active verb.

To be wrestled into a straitjacket means that somebody else is putting the straitjacket on you - and I understand that would mean you don't want it and so you are fighting back.  This is probably the sense you want.

To wrestle into a straitjacket means you are putting it on yourself (but it is kind of difficult, which is why you have to wrestle)

Comment: To be wrestled is hard to translate into my native language but can I say __to be worn by someone or get worn by someone__ ? I didn't mean same meaning, I meant structurally.

Comment: **Worn** is not a very good example, because only a garment can be worn by someone. You could say 'Many [people] had to be forced into straitjackets' or '...forced to wear straitjackets'.

Comment: The important fact about "wrestle" is that it implies a struggle.  Either it is difficult to put on the straitjacket, or the person is fighting against those who are trying to put a straitjacket on her.